# Hint for proving that $\lim_{x \to 0} \log_{10}{|x|}$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

As the title suggest, i am currently working on an exercise which asks me to prove that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \log_{10}{|x|}$$

does not exist. The proof is via contradiction.

My approach so far has been this:

*Proof*. Denote the limit by $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition of a limit, there must be a $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $$0<|x-0|<\delta$$ implies $$|\log_{10}|x|-\mathbf{L}|<\varepsilon.$$ for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is a $m$ large enough such that $10^{-m}<\delta$. Thus $$0<|10^{-m}|<\delta$$ implies $$|\log_{10}|10^{-m}|-\mathbf{L}|=|(-m\cdot\log_{10}|10|)-\mathbf{L}|=|-m-\mathbf{L}|<\frac{1}{2}. \quad  \blacksquare$$

And that is pretty much where i am stuck. The value for $\varepsilon$ whas randomly choosen, as i haven't figured which value it needs to be to create the contradiction.

I know, beggars can't be choosers, but if possible i only want a hint to nudge me in the right direction, so that i can figure out the rest of the proof by myself.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's sufficient to prove $\log_{10}|x|\to\infty$ as $x\to0$. What happens if $x<10^{-N}$?

Comment: You "definition" of limit is wrong.  No need that it holds for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts The definition in the three textbooks that i have say: $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0, \ (0<|x-c|<\delta)\implies (|f(x)-\mathbf{L}|<\varepsilon)$.

Comment: You are nearly there:  from your line let $\varepsilon = \tfrac{1}{2}$, you can say that there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $0 < x < \delta$, $|\log |x| - L| < \tfrac{1}{2}$. But then there exist some $M$ such that $10^{-m} < \delta$ for all $m \geqslant M$.  The crucial bit here is that the statement holds for all large $m$.  Your last inequality then also holds for all large $m$ which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Instead of using a proof by contradiction, I would use the negation of the definition of a limit, assuming A is the domain of the function, $\exists\epsilon_0>0,\forall\delta>0,\exists x_\delta\in A, 0<|x_\delta-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-L|\geq\epsilon_0.$

Comment: Notice in the definition of the limit that you quote, it is "$\forall \epsilon\exists \delta$", but in your attempted proof, you have "$\exists \delta \forall \epsilon$". Order matters here, very strongly.